# can't be initiateRecompile Bibliography:Pdflatex pdflatex.exe

Tags: bibliographies, errors, compiling, texstudio

I'm really struggling with this because I'm trying to put my aux files in a folder when they're compiling but it doesn't work... I've read a lot of post here about this but none is working for me

**This  is the error I get**

[image]

I put these commands in texstudio config and it worked yesterday but now it doesn't work anymore and that error appears..

**This is my config in texstudio**

[image]

if I restore the default config it compiles perfectly... but I don't like having all aux files with my .text files

I read people say thay I could use " ltx2any " but it requires Ruby ... and I don't want to install more things if my own editor can do what I really need.

If you can't see the images with the commands, these are the commands I used:

***Pflatex**: --aux-directory=build

in Texstudio: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --aux-directory=build %.tex

***Bibtex**: -include-directory=build

in Texstudio:: bibtex.exe build/% -include-directory=build

***Biber**: -include-directory=build

in Texstudio:: biber.exe build/% -include-directory=build

Comment: do you have some virus protection?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I only have the security that comes with windows,  I don't have any antivirus downloaded for me